# Почему вызывается метод класса-наследника

Tags: c#

```cs
class A
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Метода класса A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Метода класса B");
    }
}
```

<sub>Program.cs</sub>

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A b = new B();
        b.Do();
    }
}
```

Почему вызывается метод базового класса,а не дочернего,это связанно с раннем связыванием?
если:

```cs
B b = new B();
b.Do(); // Произойдет вызов метод дочернего класса,это неявное затенение от Visual Studio получается?
```

Comment: В вашем примере, вы создаёте объект типа ``B`` и приводите его к типу ``A``, поэтому при вызове метода ``Do``, происходит вызов  метода из класса ``A``

Answer (score 4):

Немного не так. Чтобы метод в классе наследнике был перезаписан, то нужно объявить в родителе метод как abstract или virtual(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual). А в классе потомке перезаписать этот метод override(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).

Если же вы этого не делаете, то в вашем случае в классе потомке два метода Do(Среда показывает ошибку сокрытия метода, в моем случае реализует только метод родителя при вызове.)

```
class A
    {
        public virtual void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Метода класса A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Метода класса B");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A b = new B();
            b.Do();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

В C# есть 2 вида вызова метода: обычный и виртуальный – вам нужен витруальный. Вот пример:

```cs
public class A
{
    public virtual void Do() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void Do() { Console.WriteLine("B") }
}
```

Пример:

```cs
A aRefsToB = new B();
A aRefsToA = new A();

aRefsToB.Do(); // B
aRefsToA.Do(); // A
```